# Why does HS1-SIV allow forgeries when the SIV collides, even when the PMN does not collide?

Tags: authenticated-encryption

The HS1-SIV authors claim that forgeries are possible if an SIV collision occurs.

However, I do not understand how this is possible unless the PMN collides too.  Otherwise, the collision  will be in the output of a PRF and will not be useful to the attacker unless the SIV is being used as an index or the like.